# Hot Network Questions icons are fuzzy

Tags: bug, status-completed, firefox, favicon

On high DPI systems, the icons for Hot Network Questions are much higher resolution on Chrome than on Firefox. I believe the problem is in the media query you're using: `@media only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5)` (`all.css` line 1, column 17049)

The correct prefixed query should be `min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5` or, better yet, the standards compliant version, `min-resolution: 1.5dppx`.

[image: Comparison between Firefox (left) and Chrome (right)]

Comment: reproduced, fixing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix is going out with next build - `2014.11.28.2809` on meta, `2014.11.28.2054` on sites.